# Linkedin OAuth unauthorized client error

Tags: linkedin-api

Getting this as the response:

```
{"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"the client is not authorized"}
```

In the final step of OAuth 2.0 to use LinkedIn APIs. Couldn't get any material regarding this,  so could anyone please help me with this ?

I am calling it as POST method too.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when I was not passing the correct value in the client_secret value in the POST to retrieve the access_token.
Once I passed in the correct value (BTW, linked calls this parameter as Secret Key on the developer console), this started working for me.

Comment: Technically invalid_client should be returned and not unauthorized_client as authorization comes after authentication